# Icon font vs SVG, which one is better for using with flutter?

Tags: android, fonts, flutter, icons

Which one if better for using in app development for the long term concerning with app size, performance and extensibility for using Icon Font and SVG icons?

Answer (score 0):

I think Icon font use better than SVG. Because of need to use a plugin to add SVG images. If you use thousand of SVG images app will be slow.